# Clone model object values Django

Tags: python, django, graphene-django

i want to clone the values from existing model object and sanitize the values for special characters to provide a better search. So i already have values in the database that i want to sanitize and store in a new object after.

This is a code example:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sanitized_headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I would like populate all the sanitized_headline objects with the corresponding headline values after some character replacements like this `re.sub('č', 'c', headline)` applied to headline before cloning, as well as do this for every new entry.

Im using Django for a GraphQl API character replacement can't be done through a view.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To sanitize the existing objects: [provided that you have a function to sanitize the text called `sanitize`]**

Enter your Django shell (using `python manage.py shell`) and import `Entry` model. Then:

```
all_entries = Entry.objects.all()
for obj in all_entries:
    obj.sanitized_headline = sanitize(obj.headline)
    obj.save()
```

**To automatically sanitize new objects, you have to override the save method:**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sanitized_headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sanitized_headline = sanitize(self.headline)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```